# which class is responsible for generating response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razorengine

I'm new to Razor Engine, just have a question on generating response in ASP.NET MVC

Firstly, we know that the role of a view engine is to translate requests for views into `ViewEngineResult` objects, and Razor view engine implements `IViewEngine`

```
public interface IViewEngine
{
   ViewEngineResult FindView(ActionContext context, string viewName, bool isMainPage);
   ViewEngineResult GetView(string executingFilePath, string viewPath, bool isMainPage);

}
```

and in `FindView` or `GetView` method, the Razor engine return a `ViewEngineResult` object as:

```
// pseudo code for simplification
if view_found 
   return ViewEngineResult.Found(viewName, new RazorView(...));
```

the `RazorView` implements `IView` as:

```
public class RazorView : IView
{
   public string Path { get; }
   public virtual Task RenderAsync(ViewContext context);
}
```

and `RenderAsync` function seems to be the guy that generates response.

but .cshtml files also get compiled into C# class by Razor engine, below is n example generated  C# code of index.cshtml:

```
public class ASPV_Views_Home_Index_cshtml : RazorPage<string[]> {
   ...
   public override async Task ExecuteAsync() {
      ...//this method also seems to generate response
   }
}
```

so `ExecuteAsync` also seems to generate response

Lastly, if we look at `ViewResult` object returned by action method, `ViewResult` implements `ActionResult`(implements `IActionResult`) as

```
public class ViewResult : ActionResult
{
  ...
  public override Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context); 
}
```

`ExecuteResultAsync` also seems to generate response.

so we have three candidates

1-`RazorView.RenderAsync()`

2-`RazorPage.ExecuteAsync()`

3-`ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync()`

which one is the real one that generate response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExecuteResultAsync` is handled differently based on the type of the result (`ViewResult`, `PageResult`, `ContentResult`, `JsonResult`, etc.). In case of `ViewResult`, its main responsibility is setting the `HttpResponse` object properties ( `StatusCode`, `ContentType`, `Body`, etc.).

Internally `ExecuteResultAsync` calls `RenderAsync` which is responsible for rendering the view and its layout.

Again, internally `RenderAsync` calls `ExecuteAsync`. `ExecuteAsync` is what does the actual rendering of the razor syntax.

You can download the .NET Core repository [AspNetCore](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore) and check the details of how everything is wired up -under `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace-.